# is there a tool/daemon that automatically fills /etc/ethers in the background to have a proper wake on lan hostname:mac database when needed?

Tags: daemon, etc, arp, wake-on-lan

is there a tool/daemon available that automatically fills /etc/ethers in the background with the proper hostname:mac pairs to have a up to date database when needed with for example wake on lan (wol) ? maybe something that does not "scan" the network, but cassually dumps the arp cache or something ?

thanks

Comment: Try `arpwatch` as a starting point

Comment: oh thats already a good one! thanks for the tip. does not yet fill the /etc/ethers , but keeps track of everything required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tool that will handle the majority of this is `arpwatch`. By default (on Debian, at least) is that it writes to `/var/lib/arpwatch/arp.dat`. This file is flushed and updated each time `arpwatch` is stopped.

The file contains entries of this form:

```
52:54:00:aa:bb:cc  192.168.1.2  1452252063  somehostname  eth0
```

The `/etc/ethers` file requires only the MAC address and either the IP address or resolvable hostname:

```
52:54:00:aa:bb:cc  192.168.1.2
```

It is then quite straightforward to keep `/etc/ethers` updated and in sync with a small script, run daily from `crontab`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Flush arp.dat
service arpwatch restart

# Save a copy
test -f /etc/ethers || touch /etc/ethers
cp -fp /etc/ethers /etc/ethers.old

# Check to see if anything new has arrived. If so rebuild the file
(
    echo '# This file is updated automatically from /var/lib/arpwatch/arp.dat'
    echo '# Take care when editing'
    echo '#'
    (
        awk '{print $1,$2}' /var/lib/arpwatch/arp.dat
        grep -v '^#' /etc/ethers.old
    ) |
        sort -u
) >/etc/ethers.tmp

# Update ethers with the new file
cmp -s /etc/ethers.tmp /etc/ethers || cat /etc/ethers.tmp >/etc/ethers
rm -f /etc/ethers.tmp

# All done
exit 0
```